# How to stop music playing with zune in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Test Process Required:

1. Play a music file.
2. Launch the application.
3. Verify that while the application loads, it does not pause, resume or stop the actively playing music.

How to make it in Silverlight?

I have something like:

```
protected void CheckMusicPlaying()
{
   if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
   {
      MessageBoxResult Choice;
      Choice = MessageBox.Show("Media is currently playing, do you want to stop it?", "Stop Player", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
      if (Choice == MessageBoxResult.OK)
         MediaPlayer.Stop(); //We simply stop their music so when they click your buttons, only yours is playing.  
   }
}
```

and in constructor: `CheckMusicPlaying();` crashes.

Comment: What's the exception when "it crashes"?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely , the above looks fine, crash may be form other part .
Please Put the Exception generated here .
Also cross verify that XNA Frame work reference is added to the application along with the using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

Answer (score 0):

it is useful to you .

i suffered with same problem finally i got solution on below url.

http://refractored.com/2010/12/05/windows-phone-7-media-player-certification-requirements/

if it have useful to you please vote for this answer.